# Android listview scroll by pixels with no delay

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a listview that I am implementing pinch zooming on. I resize each child view of the listview which changes the row height. When these rows are resized, the top item of the list view remains stationary and the items below it move up to recover the slack space.

I'm trying to implement the pinch zoom in 2 parts. First, make the zoom origin the center of the visible list (right now it's the top, like I said). Second, adjust the origin based on the focal point of the zoom gesture.

My problem is that I can't smoothly adjust the origin of the zoom. The method I have right now *does* scroll the list, but it does it a few milliseconds after the view is updated (it actually looks pretty bad... It's really choppy).

Is there a better way to do what I'm doing in the code below?

mMsgs is a listview.

```
// Center align the scroll
int yviewspace = mMsgs.getHeight();
int newyviewspace = (int) (yviewspace * zoomratio);
//mMsgs.scrollBy(0, -(yviewspace - newyviewspace) / 2); //This is smooth, but, sadly, it doesn't work on listviews.
mMsgs.smoothScrollBy(-(yviewspace - newyviewspace) / 2, 0);
```